# how to pass string from Fragments to service in android

Tags: android, android-intent, android-service

I want to pass string from fragments to service. i tried by setvalue and bind but it works with activity not with startservice right?
and what is "ServiceConnection" and by using  ServiceConnection is it possible to pass string?
here is my fragment code to start service.

I have change my code to this and it works perfect

```
Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity(), myPlayService.class);
            Bundle b = new Bundle(); 
            b.putString("link", "http://94.23.154/bbc");  
            intent.putExtras(b);
            getActivity().startService(intent);
```

and in service i used

```
public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    if(intent != null){
        Bundle bundle = intent.getExtras();
        link = bundle.getString("link");
           }
```

Comment: add string extra to the intent

Comment: sherpya can you please specify in details

Comment: in order for your question to be perfectly understandable, please put some formating and proper indentation to your code

Comment: I solve my problem.. thank you guys for giving me your time.and sorry for my poor english and editing

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can pass string from Fragment to Service via Intent and using the `putExtra()` method:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity(), myPlayService.class));
intent.putExtra("string param 1", "String for the Service");
getActivity().startService(intent);
```

In the Service you will retrieve the string in `onStartCommand()`:

```
public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
    String stringFromFragment = intent.getStringExtra("string param 1");
    // TODO do something with the string
    startPlayer();
    return START_STICKY;
}
```

Comment: yes i have already implement same kind of solution..thank you so much.

Answer (score -1):

Write code in `OnAttach` of fragment

```
@Override
    public void onAttach(Context context) {
        super.onAttach(context);
        Intent i = new Intent(getActivity(), ServiceName.class);
        i.putExtra("key",value);
        getActivity().startService(i);
  }
```